# Finding the min max and average of an array

Tags: java, arrays, max, average, min

I need to find the min, max, and average of the balances. I have done this before using for loops, but never with a while loop. Is there a way to pull the min max and average straight from the array without interfering with the while loop perhaps?

```
10
Helene 1000
Jordan 755
Eve 2500
Ken 80
Andrew 999
David 1743
Amy 12
Sean 98
Patrick 7
Joy 14
```

where 10 is the number of accounts

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class bankaccountmain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner inFile = null;
    try {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("account.txt"));
        ;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");

        System.exit(0);
    }
    int count = 0;
    int accounts = inFile.nextInt();
    String[] names = new String[accounts];
    int[] balance = new int[accounts];
    while (inFile.hasNextInt()) {
        inFile.next();
        names[count] = inFile.next();
        inFile.nextInt();
        balance[count] = inFile.nextInt();
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(balance));
    }
}
```

Comment: So what problem have you encountered?

Comment: Uh...there is no difference in how you do this with a while loop and a for loop;  You set up variables outside the loop for min, max, total, and the count.  You loop around your inFile thing updating the min, max, total, and count.  When you exit the loop you have min, max, and the average is total / count.  What is your question?

Comment: In Java 8, using a collection and the stream API, you could do it without a loop, but I am not sure as to what your exact question is, and neither do I really understand what your code does, or what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

You are already pulling the values out of the file when you store them in `balance[count]`.  You can then use those values you have just read to do your calculations:

```
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = 0;
    int total = 0;
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        names[count] = inFile.next();
        balance[count] = inFile.nextInt();  // balance[count] now is storing the value from the file

        if (balance[count] < min) {  // so I can use it like any other int
            min = balance[count];
        }
        if (balance[count] > max) {  // like this
            max = balance[count];
        }
        total += balance[count]; // and this
        count++;
    }
    double avg = (double)total/count;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of azurefrog is correct and acceptable (+1).

But I personally prefer to avoid "mixing" too much functionality. In this case: I think that

- reading the values from a file and
- computing the min/max/avg

should be separate operations.

Computing the min/max/average of an `int[]` array is a very common operation. So common that it probably already has been implemented thousands of times (and it's a pity that this functionality was not available in the standard API before Java 8).

However, if I had to implement something like this (and was not willing or allowed to use a sophisticated library solution like, for example, the [SummaryStatistics](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/SummaryStatistics.html) of Apache Commons Math), I'd go for some utility methods:

```
static int min(int array[]) 
{
    int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int a : array) result = Math.min(result, a);
    return result;
}

int max(int array[]) 
{
    int result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int a : array) result = Math.max(result, a);
    return result;
}

static int sum(int array[]) 
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int a : array) result += a;
    return result;
}

static double average(int array[]) 
{
    return (double)sum(array)/array.length;
}
```

Another advantage (apart from the "purists" argument of "Separation Of Concerns") is that these methods are reusable. You can put them into a `IntArrays` utility class, and whenever you need this functionality, you can just call these methods.

If you can already use Java 8, then it's even simpler, because exactly these operations now (finally!) **are** part of the standard API. They are offered in the [IntStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) class, that exactly has the `min()`, `max()` and `average()` methods that you need. There you could just write something like

```
int min = IntStream.of(balance).min().getAsInt();
int max = IntStream.of(balance).max().getAsInt();
double average = IntStream.of(balance).average().getAsDouble();
```

Comment: You need to read the array three time in this case while azurefrog only read it once

Comment: @Lordofdark I mentioned that the array should only be read once.