# Analasys program max and min and mode and graphing histogram

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Hi in my program I want to display the average number, largest number, lowest number, and the mode in the array. So far only my average works and my methods for min and max both = the first number I enter. For example if I say I want to enter 3 numbers and I put 12, 15,and 6. The min and max will both output 12 since it's the first number entered and that's wrong so please help. Here's my code.

```
    int amount;
    System.out.println(" Enter the amount of numbers you would like to enter: ");
    amount = scan.nextInt();

    int [] arr = new int [amount];
    int outcome = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter a number 1 through 50");
        outcome = scan.nextInt();
        arr [i] = outcome;

    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println( " The average is" ); 
    System.out.println(average(arr));
    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println( " The lowest value in the array is " ); 
    System.out.println(min(arr));
    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println( " The largest value in the array is " ); 
    System.out.println(max(arr));
    System.out.println(" ");


}





public static double average ( int [] arr) {

    double sum = 0;
    int value = arr.length;
    for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        sum += arr [i];
    }
    sum = sum / value;
    return sum;



}

public static int min (int [] arr) {
        int shortest = 0;
        int smallest = 100;
        int length = arr.length;

     for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++ ) {
        if ( length < smallest)
        shortest += arr[i];
        smallest = arr.length;
     }

       return shortest;
   }

public static int max (int [] arr) {
    int largest = 0;
    int biggest = 0;
    int length = arr.length;

 for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++ ) {
    if ( length >  largest)
    biggest += arr[i];
    largest = arr.length;
 }

   return biggest;
```

}

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the min max and average of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303225/finding-the-min-max-and-average-of-an-array)

Comment: I don't need average, I need mode, max, min and advice on how to graph a histogram.

Comment: `smallest = arr[0];` and do `biggest = arr[0];` inside your methods instead of using 100 and 0. use a value in your array instead of setting it to some value that may not even exist in your array. if your array has a size of 1, then that value would be your smallest and biggest value :)

Comment: It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be pretty straightforward. The reason both your min and max methods return 12 is because you set both largest and smallest to arr.length and thus immediately stop the for-loop after only one run. Also, there are far easier implementations for this kind of problem. Try doing something along these lines:

```
public int getMax(int[] arr)
{
  int max = arr[0];  //To have a baseline
  for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    if(arr[i] > max)
    {
      max = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
}

public int getMin(int[] arr)
{
  int min = arr[0];  //To have a baseline
  for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    if(arr[i] < min)
    {
      min = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return min;
}
```

This is both far more readable and easier to execute. Just ask if you have any questions :-)

Comment: Thank you and can you also help me find a way to get the mode.

Comment: Can you also help find a mode

Comment: What do you mean by «mode»?

Comment: If you mean the occurences of different numbers, this thread may be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946397/finding-the-mode-of-integers-in-an-array